# Django ORM filter default value which returns all objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model `Book` which has a field `year_of_publishing`. A user inputs the year and I want to filter the `Book`'s set getting all the books published in that year.

```
year = self.cleaned_data.get('year', SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE)
books = Book.objects.filter(year_of_publishing=year)
```

However the user might leave `year` field blank, and I want to put some default value, obtaining which in the `.filter` function Django ORM would return all the books like this filter was not present at all. What value should I use? I suppose it should be type independent, so I can use it for Char-, Choice- and other type of fields.

Comment: honestly, I dont understand this sentence: `I want to put some default value, obtaining which in the .filter function Django ORM would return all the books like this filter was not present at all.` can you elaborate this a bit?

Comment: I meant I'm looking for such value for which ModelName.objects.filter(field=value) would return all objects

Comment: Ah ok, then I misundertood the question, but Brandon has already hit the point, so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass an empty dictionary to `.filter()` to return all results, or filter on the fields/values you want:

```
filters = {}

year = request.GET.get('year')
if year:
    filters['year'] = year

books = Book.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just build a queryset with a dictionary:

```
parameters = ['year', 'foo', 'bar']
query_dict = {}

for parameter in parameters:
    if self.cleaned_data.get(parameter, None):
        query_dict[parameter] = self.cleaned_data.get(parameter)

books = Book.objects.filter(**query_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's quite an obvious solution, but I have a lot of fields in my form and I thought that it would be more concise if something like I had described existed

Comment: I edited the answer. You might need to pre-define what fields you want to check, but it would avoid having multiple `if` statements.